# Replace HTML Entity using JS replace( ) method

Tags: javascript

I use `&times;` HTML entity. I want to replace `&times;` by `*` using JS.

Ad far I tried...

```
val = val.replace('&times;','*');
```

and

```
val = val.replace(/&times;/g,'*');
```

Output Come: `4 × 5` But, expected output should be `4 * 5` .

```html
<html>
  <p id="entry">4 &times; 5</p>
  <script>
      var val;
      val = document.getElementById("entry").innerHTML;
  </script>
</html>
```

How to do it? Can you say what was conceptually fault I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only entities that represent special characters like `<`, `>` and `&` are returned as their entity text from innerHTML.

In this case, `&times;` doesn't represent a special character and it is converted to `×`, to replace it, you can use `.replace('×', '*')`.

Here is an example:

```js
entry.innerHTML = entry.innerHTML.replace('×', '*');
```

```html
<p id="entry">4 &times; 5</p>
```

And here is a snippet illustrating how different entities are represented by `innerHTML`:

```js
console.log(entry.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="entry">&amp; &lt; &gt; &times; &#36; &#37; &#39;</p>
```

Comment: Yes, It is work and I also understand my problem. Thanks